# IOS 3.2 MPMoviePlayerControler Controls do no disapear as advertised

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios

i was having problems to make the MPMoviePlayerController controls disappear.
I tried to do it via:

```
...
MPMoviePlayerController *mplayer;
[mplayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
...
```

The problem is however that the controls appear for a brief second. I don't want to make my app look unprofessional so making them disappear completely is what i aim for.
There is a suggestion for a [solution](http://reizencroft.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/suppressing-the-movie-controls-on-iphoneipad/#comment-242) to this problem, but i in my tests it didn't work. I also tried the old var for solving this but no effect in this case either

```
mplayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden; // old var
```

If anyone can give me hint on how to solve this it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested you can solve this by *NOT* using the MPMoviePlayerViewController.
Just use the MPMoviePlayerController and it works. Don't know why ...

Much thanks to the ppl on #iphonedev who gave me the tip.

Best regards,

zhengtonic.